# Jquery UI selectable only on if condition true

Tags: jquery

I need to make a ul as selectable only a condition is true. How to do that?

```
if($(".ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-
 list").hasClass("staged")){
   $( ".ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-
 list" ).selectable( "disable" );
 }else{
  $(.ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-
 list).selectable({});
 }
```

I need to check that dynamically added class "staged:. if they have staged class i dont want to work selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filter option of jquery selectable.

http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-filter

```
$( "ul" ).selectable({
    filter: 'li:not(.staged)'
});
```

> **EDIT**

Call selectable method on parent item. Filter by childs.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/mdg11qy2/)

Comment: It's not working because the staged class dynamically generated by a function after selectable function

Comment: so try update after class added: $(".yourAwesomeClass").selectable( "option", "filter", ".yourAwesomeClass(.staged)" ); but it should work also staged class added dynamically.